# data.sql file not pumping data to tables in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I use the spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.5.0 data.sql file doesn't get executed. But if I use version 2.4.1 everything works perfectly. I'm putting my codes below as well.

Spring Application Runner Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Entity Class:

```
package com.example.demo.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name = "car_name")
    public String carName;

    @Column(name = "car_year")
    public Integer carYear;

}
```

My application.properties File:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

My data.sql File:

```
INSERT INTO cars(car_name, car_year)
VALUES('car1', 2001);

INSERT INTO cars(car_name, car_year)
VALUES('car2', 2002);

INSERT INTO cars(car_name, car_year)
VALUES('car3', 2003);

INSERT INTO cars(car_name, car_year)
VALUES('car4', 2004);
```

My pom.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Some extra information with pictures:

[My project structure and the table created in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq6Og.jpg)

[And also I've never seen these two lines while I was running the application on spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1o9x.jpg)

I'm completely ok with just using spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.4.1 which I was using until now, but I'm also so curious about the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql) says to set

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

to allow Hibernate to create the schema before loading data.sql.

Comment: Oh god, everyone everywhere saying that i had to set initialization-mode to true and I already did that, this answer saved my day

Answer (score 5):

I can see they have mentioned it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql):

> By default, data.sql scripts are now run before Hibernate is
> initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based
> initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use
> data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set
> spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true. While mixing
> database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will
> also allow you to use a schema.sql script to build upon a
> Hibernate-created schema before it’s populated via data.sql.

So you can try

```yaml
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

A worth read [9.3. Initialize a Database Using Basic SQL Scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)

Comment: for my didn't work with spring boot 2.2.13